# How to navigate to another tab from one tab(pane manager model) in blackberry?

Tags: sqlite, blackberry, user-interface, tabs, navigation

I have created 3 tabs in my blackberry application.The first tab allows the user to select a particular date range and search for entries.The search button is on first tab.The results are fetched from a sqlite database and displayed on grid view of third tab.
This is the main code i have used for creating tabs:

```
  // setup the tab model with 3 tabs
  PaneManagerModel model = new PaneManagerModel();
  model.enableLooping( true );

  // setup the first tab
  VerticalFieldManager vfm = new VerticalFieldManager( 
      Field.USE_ALL_HEIGHT | Field.USE_ALL_WIDTH |
      Manager.NO_VERTICAL_SCROLL | Manager.NO_HORIZONTAL_SCROLL );
  LabelField lbl = new LabelField( "Content for tab 1", Field.FOCUSABLE );
  vfm.add( lbl );

  MyLabelField myLbl = new MyLabelField( "Tab 1" );
  NullField nullFld = new NullField( Field.FOCUSABLE );
  HorizontalFieldManager hfm = new HorizontalFieldManager();
  hfm.add( nullFld );
  hfm.add( myLbl );

  Pane pane = new Pane( hfm, vfm );
  model.addPane( pane );


  // setup the second tab
  vfm = new VerticalFieldManager( 
      Field.USE_ALL_HEIGHT | Field.USE_ALL_WIDTH |
      Manager.NO_VERTICAL_SCROLL | Manager.NO_HORIZONTAL_SCROLL );
  lbl = new LabelField( "Content for tab 2", Field.FOCUSABLE );
  vfm.add( lbl );

  myLbl = new MyLabelField( "Tab 2" );
  nullFld = new NullField( Field.FOCUSABLE );
  hfm = new HorizontalFieldManager();
  hfm.add( nullFld );
  hfm.add( myLbl );

  pane = new Pane( hfm, vfm );
  model.addPane( pane );

  //Setup the third tab
  vfm = new VerticalFieldManager( 
      Field.USE_ALL_HEIGHT | Field.USE_ALL_WIDTH |
      Manager.NO_VERTICAL_SCROLL | Manager.NO_HORIZONTAL_SCROLL );
  lbl = new LabelField( "Content for tab 3", Field.FOCUSABLE );
  vfm.add( lbl );

  myLbl = new MyLabelField( "Tab 3" );
  nullFld = new NullField( Field.FOCUSABLE );
  hfm = new HorizontalFieldManager();
  hfm.add( nullFld );
  hfm.add( myLbl );

  pane = new Pane( hfm, vfm );
  model.addPane( pane );
```

At present the results are properly getting displayed in third tab.But they are not on button click of fist tab.

I have included my SELECT statement in the third tab content.Instead i want to display the third tab results only after i click on search from the first tab.Till then i want my third tab to be disabled or rather inactive.

Anyone having any idea on this please share.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You cau call [`PaneManagerView.jumpTo(int,int)`](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/component/pane/PaneManagerView.html#jumpTo%28int,%20int%29).

Comment: I have included this PaneManagerView.jumpTo(3,DIRECTION_BACKWARDS); within the try statement of my first tab.This try statement is used to fetch results from table.But on compiling i am getting error: non-static method jumpTo(int,int) cannot be referenced from a static context
                        PaneManagerView.jumpTo(3,DIRECTION_BACKWARDS);  Second error: cannot find symbol    ^
                        PaneManagerView.jumpTo(3,DIRECTION_BACKWARDS);
                         ^

Comment: Sorry, my code was not meant to be pasted as is. `jumpTo` is not static, so you need to call it on your instance of PaneManager: `model.getView().jumpTo(3, DIRECTION_FORWARDS)`

Comment: Yes that worked!Thanks a ton.I used index 2 for tab 3, it worked perfectly.Thanks again.Any idea how to disable that tab 3 till the time this button event is clicked.

Comment: There's no direct API to do that. As an alternative, you can have a dummy pane with no content on tab 3, and then when you are about to switch to it, calll `model.replacePane` to replace the dummy for the real one. Or you can just create the PaneManager without tab #3, then add it just before switching.

Comment: Actually the thing is that i have included the grid display statements in tab 3 but the actual fetching of data is taking place in tab 1,because of which the tab3 always shows the previously fetched data and not the current data that i wanted from tab1.So i want to completely disable tab3.Otherwise how can i include those statements of tab3 in this tab1.Please see the reedits for tab 3 code.

Comment: You could create a holder object (with attributes for DailyReport, Date, Bill, etc). When you want to update tab3 either with default values or with newly fetched data, fill a holder object instance with the info, and call a new method `updateTab3(MyHolderObject)`. That method basically would call `grid.insert` at the appropiate cells. As for how to disable the tab, I said what I think in the previous comment.

Comment: Can u provide me a suitable link to this creation of holder object in blackberry.I have never tried out doing this.Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: It would be just a regular Java class with attributes, to have a handy way of passing info. You can also just pass the data as parameters in the method. The main idea is to separate code accessing the DB from the code updating the GUI.

Comment: model.getView().setEnabled(false); enables disabling of pane.But hard luck on that too as its leading to run time error.All the 3 tabs are created as soon as the button is clicked.I am not able to figure out where to use that piece of code.As i want first 2 tabs to be created but not the third.The 3rd tab should get created only when a button from tab 1 is clicked.Any idea how to go about it.

Comment: Man, your old code almost did that. The only thing to change would be to remove the call to `model.addPane(pane)` for the third tab and do it instead when button on tab1 is clicked. Get sure to make this call while holding the event lock or using `invokeLater` or `invokeAndWait`, which are methods in UiApplication class.

Comment: Nothings happening dude.Still cant seem a way outta this problem.Tried with the invokelater but somethings going wrong with the run time.