# Restrict opening of all tabs in blackberry application

Tags: java, blackberry, tabs, navigation, restriction

I have 3 tabs in my application form which are opened when a button from previous form is clicked.

The below image shows the 3 tabs when opened.

As seen, when the search button from first tab is clicked, it jumps to the third tab after searching the results.

Similarly when group button is clicked it opens the second tab again after searching results from database and filling into the grid layout defined within tabs 2 and 3

[image]

Grid layouts have been used for tabs 2 and 3 so that values from table are retrieved string wise.

Now the problem being faced is that these  tabs SECOND and THIRD are fetching junk values before hitting the search button from tab1

This is because the tab layout is initialized together for all the 3 tabs.

Is there any way i can avoid these 2 tabs(that is Second & Third Tab) from opening as soon as this form for tabs is opened.(NOTE: This tab form is opened on clicking a button from previous homescreen form)

Please check this for my code used earlier [How to navigate to another tab from one tab(pane manager model) in blackberry?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10473476/how-to-navigate-to-another-tab-from-one-tabpane-manager-model-in-blackberry)

Please communicate if any more understanding of question is needed.